# wrong version libxml when installing libxslt

Tags: linux, libxml2

I'm using Centos 5.1.
On this OS libxml2.so.2.6.26 is installed in the folder /usr/lib/
For the build of my project I als need libxslt. When installing I get the error :" checking for libxml libraries >= 2.6.27... configure: error: Version 2.6.26 found. You need at least libxml2 2.6.27 for this version of libxslt". 
I installed the newest version of libxml in a different folder, but now I'm not able to tel libxslt to look for libxml in this new folder (used --prefix & --libdir) . It keeps finding version 2.6.26 in the lib-folder. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add path of newest version of libxml libs to  **--with-libxml-libs-prefix** while configuring libxslt

```
cd libxslt
./configure --with-libxml-libs-prefix="path to your newest libxml"
```

also try `./configure --help` for more information

Comment: I already tried this and also added the --with-libxml-prefix and --with-libxml-include-prefix. The result I get then is : "checking for libxml libraries >= 2.6.27... configure: error: Could not find libxml2 anywhere, check ftp://xmlsoft.org/."

Comment: If you get this error, check that `PREFIX/bin/xml2-config` exists and is executable.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev